# Apply css to classes with onclick events

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I have a menu on the left of my page that is made of nested uls.  On the right of my page I have a series of content div's that all have a class that corresponds with the menu link on the left.  When you click a menu link on the left it needs to hide all of my content divs, then show only those that have the corresponding class.  So if you click the link "Implementation/System development" the page will first hide all divs of class "content", then show all divs of class "content5".

As a complication to this the menu has some javascript attached to the ul's that show and hide the nested menues.  I don't want to touch it or interfere with it because it works.  Also I don't think it would be usable to solve my problem because it watches all menu li's and I don't know how to tie one menu items action to that general function.

What I think I need is to add an onclick event that sets the display of all my content divs to none, and sets a subset to block.  The menu is generated server side, so I can add attributes to it.

My thought process is chance the menu links to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="swap_content(content5)">Implementation/System development</a>
```

Then have code that changes the css like:

```
swap_content([target]){
    div.content{ display:none;}
    div.[target]{ display:block;}
}
```

That way it hides all the currently displayed content then only shows the content tied to that link.

```
<div class='content content26 content27 content28 content29 content30'></div>
```

1. Will using onclick interfere with the expanding/collapsing from
   jquery?  I think that the opening and closing rely on watching the
   class of the ul's, ul.menu1, ul.menu2 and so on since there are no
   onclick events.
2. I can't think of a way to associate the link with
   it's target content on the server side other than explicitly passing
   it to the swap_content function in the onclick.

I am completely new to javascript so this may be completely boneheaded, but any help or guidance would be appreciated.  The test page is up [here](http://nwi.pdx.edu/pubsearch3.php) if you want to take a look.  In the example the content divs are already set to `display:none;`.

The code driving the opening and closing of the menu is at http://nwi.pdx.edu/jQueryScripts/pubs-search-script.js but like I said, it works, I really don't want to touch it all that much.

Comment: To get the accurate working solution, you need to provide code for menu that you are using

Comment: I have a test page up at http://nwi.pdx.edu/pubsearch3.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the display propert of the divs and all content in them to "inherit.

From that put them all in a container such as a span or div tag then in that span or div add the following code:

```
onclick="style.display = 'none'"
```

That will hide everything in that tag that inherits the display property from it.

Update: give the tag that contains all the divs that you want to hide an id such as id = "thing".

Your hide function should look something like:

```
function hide ()
 {
  document.getElementById("thing").style.display = "none";
 }
```

then in your html on the item you want to click to make it happen add

```
onclick="hide()"
```

Update Numerou Dos: You can use JavaScript's JQuery library to select by class by doing something like:

```
$(."hider").click(function(){$(".myClass").css("display","none");});
```

Where myClass is the name of your class and hider is the class of whatever it is your clicking to make it happen. Also if you do it this way (there's a couple others ways to do it using class selectors) remove the onclick function from your hider.

Comment: but the div's I want to hide are not in any way connected to the links that I want to trigger this event.

Comment: the menu links and the divs they will effect are in completely different sections of the DOM tree.

Comment: Edited my post with a new solution that should allow you to hid the divs by click an unconnected element. You still need to make divs and all items in the div inherit their display property from their parent element. If you want to make it unhide you should add an if statement to JS function.

Comment: This is really close but I need to select nodes to change style by one of multiple classes the node has not by id.

Comment: I may have found a solution. Are you able to use JQuery (a JavaScript Library)? It has selectors for class properties.